# Existence of a Probability Measure with given Fourier Coefficients

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-series, fourier-transform, trigonometric-series

Let fix $c_1, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb{C}$ for some $n \geq 1$. I would like to know when does it exist a probability measure $\mathcal{P}$ over the torus $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\widehat{\mathcal{P}} [k] = c_k$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, where $\widehat{\mathcal{P}}[k] = \int_{\mathbb{T}} \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm{i} \pi k x} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{P} (x)$.

One necessary condition is that $\lvert c_k \rvert \leq 1$ for any $k$ due to
$$|\widehat{\mathcal{P}} [k] | \leq \int_{\mathbb{T}} \mathrm{d}\mathcal{P}(x) = 1.$$

**Question:** Is the proposed condition sufficient for the existence of $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: It seems that you may want to check the Bochner-Herglotz theorem.

Comment: Sounds relevant. With this theorem, it gives me a stronger necessary condition, i.e., $\sum_{i,j=0}^n \widehat{\mathcal{P}}[i-j] z_j z_j^* \geq 0$ for any $z_i \in \mathbb{C)}$. But this does not solve fully answer, am I right?

Comment: No it does not solve it completely, since you only have a finite number of such coefficients. I think that there is no unique measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$ that has $n$ first Fourier nodes $c_1,\ldots,c_n$. This also reminds me also of Wiener's lemma.